# parse.com Updating object creates new object ID

Tags: parse-platform

I am new to Parse. I am trying to update a object already saved on the parse backend.  I use the getObjectInBackgroundWithID and supply the object ID.  When I try and update with new data the app tells me it successfully save a new record and when i look on the backend, I now have two records with different object ID's.  Below is my code in the update button.  In my app it passes in the object ID, but I have tried hard coding the object ID with the same result.

@IBAction func updateAccountPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Accounts")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("dS7fHCoabI") {
        (accountInfo: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else if let accountInfo = accountInfo {

            accountInfo["Type"] = self.pickedAccontType
            accountInfo["NumberOrNickname"] = self.accountNumNickname.text
            accountInfo["InitialBalance"] = self.initialBalance.text
            accountInfo.saveInBackground()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
...
} else if let accountInfo = accountInfo {
...
```

You are actually creating a new variable called `accountInfo` and assigning the object you fetched to it. You are then calling the `saveInBackground()` method on a new `PFObject` you just created, thus creating a new record in Parse. Just change your `if` statement:

```
if error != nil {
    print(error)
} else {
    accountInfo["Type"] = self.pickedAccountType
    accountInfo["NumberOrNickname"] = self.accountNumNickname.text
    accountInfo["InitialBalance"] = self.initialBalance.text
    accountInfo.saveInBackground()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  when I take that out I get the error "Cannot subscript a value of type 'PFObject?'".  I can clear the error if i put a "!" after accountInfo, but when I do that it is still creating another record in Parse.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had somehow linked my updated button with both my update and the add func.  After removing the link it updates fine with no new objectID.